# find a charcter in file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find the some character in file using find or findstr? for e.g file contents like:

> "/test/abctest/abci.txt = c:\abctest\tst\work\workt.txt;**abc**_test1"
>   "/test/abctest/abci.txt = c:\abctest\tst\work\workt.txt;**abc**.test2"
>   "/test/abctest/abci.txt = c:\abctest\tst\work\workt.txt;**(abc)**test3"
>   "/test/abctest/abci.txt = c:\abctest\tst\work\workt.txt;**abc**_test4"

... so on... I want to find in file last abc (bold part). This file very large, So I dnt want to use any for loop to find character. Could you please suggest me any solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Do you want to return the bolded text from all lines? Or do you only want the bolded text from the last line? Or do you want the entire last line that contains bolded text? How do you know what should be bolded? For example, why are parentheses included in 3rd line?

Comment: No, If I got only one types of bolded string in anywhere in file then exit.

Comment: Ok, you simply want to test for the existence of some text on any line within the file. But you still haven't specified what your search rules are. FINDSTR has primitive regex capabilities. It probably can do what you want.

Comment: FINDSTR is only searching word. I think.

Comment: `FINDSTR /?` could explain it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is the regexp you want, but if all you want to do is exit if the regexp matches, then

```
findstr /i ";[^a-z]*[a-z][a-z][a-z][^a-z]" datafile.txt >NUL && exit /b
```

This performs a case-insensitive search for `/;\W?\w{3}\W/` in more sensible regexp notation.  If found, `exit /b`, otherwise do nothing.